# How set up access to file on local filesystem for MySQL running on the docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I install MySQL5.6 in the docker.

I create docker-compose.ym and set properties for db

```
db:
  container_name: db_mysql
  image: mysql:5.6
  command: --secure-file-priv='/var/lib/'
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: devdb
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"

  volumes:
     - /home/marina/some-path:/var/lib/
```

but I can't use function

SELECT LOAD_FILE('/home/marina/some-path/some-path-more/image.jpg').

How can I configure volume to access my files from the docker?

```
Need mount my local file system to docker machine
# Create the "default" machine, but then stop it.
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
docker-machine stop
# Add a new shared folder through virtualbox
VBoxManage sharedfolder add default --name "userhome" --hostpath 
"/home/marina/"
# Turn the machine back on, and mount the share
docker-machine start
docker-machine ssh default 'sudo mkdir --parents /home/marina'
docker-machine ssh default 'sudo mount -t vboxsf userhome /home/marina'
# Check it works
docker-machine ssh default 'ls /home/marina'
# Start it up
docker-compose up
```

and change volume to:

```
volumes:
    - /home/marina/workprojectdir:/home/marina/workprojectdir
```

and set command:

```
command: --secure-file-priv=''
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would avoid using `/var/lib` as a container path because this path normally exists and you can damage the data inside container. Use something like:

```
volumes:
  - /home/marina/some-path:/mydata
```

Second, I guess you are confusing host path and container path. With your example given, inside container you should use something like this `SELECT LOAD_FILE('/mydata/image.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping to /var/lib/mysql instead. Mapping /var/lib is not recommended.

```
db:
  container_name: db_mysql
  image: mysql:5.6
  command: --secure-file-priv='/var/lib/mysql'
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: devdb
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"

  volumes:
     - /home/marina/some-path:/var/lib/mysql
```

- Copy image.jpg into `/home/marina/some-path` on your container host. This will map the file under `/var/lib/mysql` inside the container.
- Bash into the container
  `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`
- Run 
  `SELECT LOAD_FILE('/var/lib/mysql/image.jpg')`

Comment: I can't mount anyway. Folder inside docker doesn't conains file which existed in the local system.

I change volume

     /home/marina/work:/home/marina/work

Comment: I doesn't mount volume for docker-machine. It's problem.

Comment: Cool. Instructions to mount a folder inside docker-machine
https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/mount/